# How to make something stay connected between two times?

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32

I am creating a project for Arduino using an ESP32.

It is currently configured for testing only, but I have already identified a problem but I don't know what the code would look like to fix it.

I want her to leave the LED on between the hours of 7 pm and 6 am, but I've already realized that if the power goes out during the night, she won't understand that it's time to leave the LED on and will only perform the function programmed for 6 am.

Can anyone help me, or explain to me how I can get around this situation?

Below is the source code:

```
#include <NTPClient.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>
#include <WiFi.h>

#define LED 2
#define command 4
#define sensor 19

const char* ssid = "SSID_NETWORK";
const char* password = "PASS_NETWORK";

WiFiUDP ntpUDP;
NTPClient timeClient(ntpUDP, "pool.ntp.org");

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(1000);
        Serial.println("Conectando ao WiFi...");
    }
    Serial.println("Conectado ao WiFi.");
    digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(LED, LOW);

    timeClient.begin();
    timeClient.setTimeOffset(-3 * 3600); // Ajuste o fuso horário para o Brasil (GMT-3)

    pinMode (LED, OUTPUT);
    pinMode (sensor, OUTPUT);
    pinMode (command, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {
    timeClient.update();
    Serial.println(timeClient.getFormattedTime());

    // Verifique os horários e execute funções conforme necessário
    if (timeClient.getHours() == 19 && timeClient.getMinutes() == 00 && timeClient.getSeconds() == 00) {
        // Execute uma função no horário determinado
            digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(sensor, HIGH);
//            digitalWrite(command, HIGH)
//            delay(1000);
//            digitalWrite(command, LOW)
    } else {
      // Excute algo fora do horário não necessário
    }

    if (timeClient.getHours() == 06 && timeClient.getMinutes() == 00 && timeClient.getSeconds() == 00) {
      // Executa a função no horário determinado

      digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
      digitalWrite(sensor, LOW);
    }


    // Outros horários e funções podem ser adicionados aqui

    delay(100); // Aguarde um minuto antes de verificar novamente
}
```

I've already looked for ways for it to check the latest time and reactivate the function, but I haven't found any way to do this yet.

Comment: Instead of writing the pins on the edge of clock, write them on every run of the loop:`bool on = is_night_time(timeClient); digitalWrite(LED, on ? HIGH : LOW);` define `is_night_time` to be between 7pm and 6am.

Comment: you should check that timeClient has a big epoc time, which means it'ssynced with a server. Sometimes the net gets backed up so the time is wrong the first loops. That would blink the light in the middle of the night...

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change some conditions and you will get your desired results. Here is your updated code:

```
#include <NTPClient.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>
#include <WiFi.h>

#define LED 2
#define command 4
#define sensor 19

const char* ssid = "SSID_NETWORK";
const char* password = "PASS_NETWORK";

WiFiUDP ntpUDP;
NTPClient timeClient(ntpUDP, "pool.ntp.org");

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(1000);
        Serial.println("Conectando ao WiFi...");
    }
    Serial.println("Conectado ao WiFi.");
    digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(LED, LOW);

    timeClient.begin();
    timeClient.setTimeOffset(-3 * 3600); // Ajuste o fuso horário para o Brasil (GMT-3)

    pinMode (LED, OUTPUT);
    pinMode (sensor, OUTPUT);
    pinMode (command, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {
    timeClient.update();
    Serial.println(timeClient.getFormattedTime());

    uint8_t hour = timeClient.getHours();

    // Verifique os horários e execute funções conforme necessário
    if ((hour >=19) || (hour < 6) ) {
        // Execute uma função no horário determinado
            digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(sensor, HIGH);
//            digitalWrite(command, HIGH)
//            delay(1000);
//            digitalWrite(command, LOW)
    } else {
      // Excute algo fora do horário não necessário
    }

    if ((hour >=6) && (hour < 19)) {
      // Executa a função no horário determinado

      digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
      digitalWrite(sensor, LOW);
    }


    // Outros horários e funções podem ser adicionados aqui

    delay(100); // Aguarde um minuto antes de verificar novamente
}
```